# Why use googlemail smtp server instead of your server?

Tags: email, debian, gmail, smtp, postfix

I ran into this post: [Getting Postfix to work on Ubuntu with Gmail](http://prantran.blogspot.com.es/2007/01/getting-postfix-to-work-on-ubuntu-with.html) which describes how to use gmail as relayhost for postfix.

And I'm wondering what would be the benefits of doing so?

I have some dedicated servers that use postfix to send emails to clients. And I also have googlemail to manage the same domain emails. Would it be better to use gmail as relayhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an older question but felt another answer was needed.

Running a mailserver properly is hard work these days, with staying off blacklists, IP-reputation, DKIM, SPF, etc. etc. It's tough to get your mails into the inboxes of providers like Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, etc.

If your sending from each server directly you have to take care of all that, for each server separately. Instead, you can relay all your outgoing mail through an SMTP relay. Gmail is one option. Services like https://sendgrid.com/ and https://mandrill.com/ are more specialized in this. They usually offer a free tier that may suffice depending on the amount of mail
you send and aren't harder to set up than gmail's smtp.

A benefit of a specialized mail relays is the extra information they provide. I get a centralized dashboard of mail traffic from all my servers so I don't need to gather Postfix logs from the individual servers. I can quickly see mail volume, delivery problems, search for individual mails or find patterns, etc. and the service will handle smtp reputation for me to prevent delivery problems. In my experience, delivery rates went up while I spent less time on it.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I've learned from experience, and I actually use a dedicated service to manage all sent emails.

Answer (score 0):

I use exim on my laptop, and it need a relayhost that work wherever I'm. Gmail give me that.

Another use for this, it to have the mail you send in gmail outbox.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, using googlemail as relayhost is just in case you don't have a reliable smtp server. It does not have special other benefits?

Comment: It have the benefit to store the send mail for NSA to read it latter... A I mean to let you have it in the webmail of gmail, in its place in the discussion.